# Странное поведение в функции javascript

Tags: javascript, android, плагин, phonegap

В проекте phonegap+android у меня есть функция:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

Если я добавляю в эту функцию

```
$('#note').text('checkConnection');
```

перед строкой

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

то текст изменяется (текст 'checkConnection' становится виден), если после этой строки - то нет. Почему так происходит, это же просто объявление переменной?

Comment: Потому что в строке `var networkState = navigator.connection.type;` - ошибка. Выполнение на ней прерывается. `navigator` или `navigator.connection` неопределены. Добавьте `console.log(navigator);console.log(navigator.connection);` в начало функции.

Comment: есть ли возможность посмотреть возможные ошибки?

Comment: @Igor, и на то, и на другое выдаёт [OBJECT OBJECT]

Comment: `console.log(navigator.connection.type);`?

Comment: @Igor, кажется, эта функция в Android Studio ничего не выводит..

Comment: @Grundy, в logcat ничего особо вразумительного я не нашла...  http://joxi.ru/L21v06Ru8vgBjA

Comment: не уверен, но похоже logcat не совсем тот лог, который нужен

Comment: Попробовала вывести console.log через Android Device Monitor, получилось. В функции следующие строки добавились:  http://joxi.ru/J2b91g3TXlGkdm, вывод следующий: http://joxi.ru/D2P4Dz8upvkQd2

Comment: Т.е., строка console.log(navigator); всё равно выводится как [object Object]

Comment: А ошибка, по-видимому, эта: 05-05 21:10:23.321: D/SystemWebChromeClient(21057): file:///android_asset/www/js/connection_check.js: Line 9 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: @Ksenia разбирайтесь, почему `navigator.connection` неопределено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась после добавления следующего метода:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCheckConn").click(function() {
        checkConnection();
    });
});
```

Comment: а раньше эта функция где вызывалась?

Comment: @Grundy нетрудно догадаться

Comment: @Grundy, просто в `<script>checkConnection();</script>` )